# Cannot copy sheet to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have what it seems a small issue but cannot figure out how to solve.
So, every week I have to make a bunch of pivot tables to summarize raw data that I am getting. I figured, it would be much easier if I create all the tables into a Layout file and then just copy them to the new file and then change the source. And I wrote the following code:

```
Sub something()

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\\\\Layout.xlsx"
With Workbooks("Layout.xlsx")
    .Sheets("Pivot").Copy Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main List")
    .Close savechanges:=False
End With

End Sub
```

This code works just fine. The issue comes when I try to paste the code into my personal workbook and then run through VBA directly, rather than copying and pasting it every time.

What I could do is, to change the code from 'Activeworkbook' to the name of my new workbook but its name change every week, because it is based on a date. 
I already tried to declare the name of the new workbook as a string and call it through that but that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Rather than a string as you suggest, have you tried defining the workbook as a workbook object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use workbook objects to keep the two files clear:

```
Sub something()

    Dim wb_from As Workbook, wb_to As Workbook
    Set wb_to = ActiveWorkbook
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\\\\Layout.xlsx"
    Set wb_from = Workbooks("Layout.xlsx")
    wb_from.Sheets("Pivot").Copy Before:=wb_to.Sheets("Main List")
    wb_from.Close SaveChanges:=False
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked. There was a typo just after 'before:=' and got an error on the same line. :D But it is great now.